# convert uppercase letters to lower case

Tags: javascript, algorithm, iteration

I know there are lots of discussions about how to convert characters in a string to all be lower case.  My question is why my implementation below is failing.

CODE:

```
let str = 'aAaA';

const makeLowerCase = (string) => {
  for ( var i = 0; i < string.length; i++ ) {
    let lower = string[i].toLowerCase(); 
    if (string[i] !== lower ) {
      string[i] = lower;
    } 
  }
}

console.log('before', str);
makeLowerCase(str);
console.log('after', str);
```

Output in console:

```
before aAaA
after aAaA
```

Even though for indexes 1 and 3 the if statement test should pass, the code in that block is evidently not running or is running but not having the expected outcome.

Thanks all.

Comment: Strings in Javascript are immutable, you can't change them once they are set. But why are you converting each character instead the whole string? `str.toLowerCase`

Comment: strings are immutable. you need an assingment of the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript strings are immutable. So you can not change the string using `C` programming style. Rather use the following code

```js
let str = 'aAaA';

const makeLowerCase = (string) => {
  for ( var i = 0; i < string.length; i++ ) {
    let lower = string[i].toLowerCase(); 
    if (string[i] !== lower ) {
      string = string.substring(0,i)+lower+string.substring(i+1);
    } 
  }
  return string;
}

console.log('before', str);
str = makeLowerCase(str);
console.log('after', str);
```

You can also simply call `toLowerCase()` method on the whole string unless you have any reason to run the loop. Like following:

```js
let str = 'aAaA';
str = str.toLowerCase();
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Close for statement and add the following

```
Return string
```

Run

```
Console.log(makeLowerCase(...))
```

Or `const str = makeLowerCase(...); console.log(str)`